# Need help for Java Condition Code Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

Need to select from dropdown. if selected yes i need to fill certain text field and if no then other text field need to be completed. using selenium java and i need help on how to write if else statement.
i have entered my complete code for your information.

enter code here

```
    <WebElement JointApplication=driver.findElement(By.id("-1-1-joint_life"));      
    Select Joint=new Select(JointApplication);

    Joint.selectByVisibleText("No");

    Thread.sleep(6000);

    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//SELECT[contains(@style,'width: 102%;')]")).isDisplayed())
    {
        // if we select yes for Joint Application

        WebElement Title=driver.findElement(By.id("dd-2-1-title1"));
        Select Tit=new Select(Title);
        Tit.selectByVisibleText("Mr");
        driver.findElement(By.id("-2-1-fullname1")).sendKeys("Test ");
        driver.findElement(By.id("-2-1-csurname1")).sendKeys("Automatioan");
        driver.findElement(By.id("-2-1-nino")).sendKeys("SK119944B");
        driver.findElement(By.id("-1-d_o_b1")).sendKeys("01");
        driver.findElement(By.id("-1-d_o_b2")).sendKeys("01");
        driver.findElement(By.id("-1-d_o_b3")).sendKeys("1990");




    }
    else 
    {

        WebElement COB=driver.findElement(By.id("-2-1-cntry_bth"));
        Select birth=new Select(COB);
        birth.selectByVisibleText("United Kingdom");
        driver.findElement(By.id("-2-1-place_bth")).sendKeys("London");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement Nationality=driver.findElement(By.id("-2-1-nat_ality"));
        Select Nation=new Select(Nationality);
        Nation.selectByVisibleText("United Kingdom");



    }>
```

Comment: Help with writing what exactly?

Comment: I am using if else statement and its not executing the if else statement. I am able to execute only one statement

Comment: Are you sure? you have the exact same code in the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: My testing requirement is when the application is joint it has different text fields and if it is single application is has diff fields. Code is correct , but i am struggling with java logic

Comment: @Arjun Your code says: "if this contition is true, do this, if it is not true, do the same thing". Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: My requirement is if selected Yes then enter certain text fields  or else enter different text field. i can send the screen shot of my screen

Comment: can you send the screenshot @Arjun

Comment: I have emailed you Koushick

Comment: Hi Koushick , can you please help on below issue(link) sqa.stackexchange.com/q/36421/35535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the IF statement itself, doing

```
if(JointApplication.getAttribute("value").contains("No")){
  //do this
} else {
  //do this
}
```

should work. It will look for the value set in the select statement.

Although, I don't fully understand the need for the if statement in this context. If you know you are setting it to either Yes or No, why not fill out other fields accordingly?

Comment: Hi, the reason i want to use if else statement is if i select yes then i  need to fill 2 applications and if i select No i need to fill 1 application.i am using data driven framework and i can't execute the complete code for yes and No

Comment: Hi Arild, can you please help on below issue(link)                       https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/36421/35535